# how to compile c/cpp code in such a way that it gives preprocessed assembled and object file after compilation in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

if source file is source.cpp then compiler output should have source.i source.s 
source.o in my directory not only .o file.

where

> 1. preprocessed = source.i
> 2. assembly = source.s
> 3. object = source.o

i know first two files are being created but later on they got deleted only .o file is
shown so that linker can link object file but i want to see those two files also.

for linux any flag or something?.

Comment: do a simple `man gcc`

Comment: ...and get the switches required to generate the particular files (and possibly chnage your makefile to breakdown the single stage compilation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create individual file for each stage of compiler.

**Preprocessor :**
`g++ -E file.cpp -o file.i`

**Translator :**
`g++ -S file.i -o file.s`

**Assembler :**
`g++ -c file.s -o file.o`

**linker :**
`g++ file.o -o file`

Answer (score 8):

According to the gcc man pages

> -save-temps
>     -save-temps=cwd
>              Store the usual "temporary" intermediate files permanently; place them in the current directory and name them based on the source file.  Thus, compiling foo.c with -c -save-temps would produce files foo.i and foo.s, as well as foo.o.  This creates a
>              preprocessed foo.i output file even though the compiler now normally uses an integrated preprocessor.

so you should compile your code like this

```
g++ -save-temps source.cpp
```